# How to handle Cocoapod dependency?

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, rmstore

I'm creating my first cocoapod. It has a dependency on `RMStore`, so I added `s.dependency "RMStore"` to the podspec file. However, when I'm working on my framework, I always get errors saying that `RMStore` isn't available. So how do I handle this?

Comment: Did you add the pod RMStore in the podfile of the project where you are developping your own pod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding `s.dependency`, you do indeed need to run `pod install` against your project so that the pods download and the pods project correctly references everything. Assuming you have an Example/Tester project with a Podfile that points to "your pod", this will download RMStore and configure everything for you.

I prepared an example of how to do dependencies in developed pods and it's available here:

https://github.com/ericwastaken/CocoaPod-Dependency-Demo